# Unable to change version of node with brew switch

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'm trying to use node 8.9.1 but when trying to update using brew it says 8.9.1 is already installed

```
James-MacBook:~ james$ brew upgrade node
Error: node 8.9.1 already installed
```

But when checking the version it shows

```
James-MacBook:~ james$ node --version
    v0.10.48
```

So then I tried to switch to 8.9.1

```
James-MacBook:~ james$ brew switch node 8.9.1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1
7 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1
```

But it is still showing as 0.10.48

```
James-MacBook:~ james$ node --version
v0.10.48
```

Comment: try deleting node / npm and reinstall it

Comment: I've done that including removing all reference of node/npm following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) instructions

Comment: try `node --version` in a new shell.

Comment: @bfontaine unfortunately still showing 0.10.48 even in a new shell

Comment: This should no longer be an issue when attempting to install the latest version of node.js today.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you have some version of node that is installed without using Homebrew.

1. First of all, check if you installed your node with nvm by check if you have a .nvm directory in home directory `ls -la`

   2. if you do, remove that directory
   3. `brew update && brew install node@8` (whichever node you want)
   4. `brew unlink node@0`
   5. `brew link --force node@8`
   6. Do brew update && brew upgrade node@8

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Nvm package... kind of slows down your terminal upon startup. I found it annoying....

You can always just uninstall node and install  node that’s compatible with npm on
**Nodejs.org**  link below

[All node version  link <-](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) !

look for **pkg if your mac user**, and **msi for windows users**