# How to remove older version of Node and switch to new version?

Tags: node.js, homebrew

When I `node -v` I get `v7.10.0`

I've installed with `brew install node` and `brew upgrade node` I see that 9.5 got installed.

I did `brew switch node 9.5.0` and got 7 links created for `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0`

However when I reopen the terminal my node -v is still v7.10.0 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here, I needed to remove my `.nvm` folder

[Unable to change version of node with brew switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295359/unable-to-change-version-of-node-with-brew-switch)

> First of all, check if you installed your node with nvm by check if you have a .nvm directory in home directory ls -la
>   if you do, remove that directory