# Node version issue when creating Vue CLI 3 app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have installed the latest Vue CLI to version 3.1.3.

I'm trying to create a new app with `vue create app`

This goes fine until Yarn tries to install the dependancies:

```
yarn install v1.12.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error eslint@5.9.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". Got "8.9.4"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 ERROR  command failed: yarn
```

`node --version` shows I'm using 8.9.4.

When I try to update node via homebrew I get an error saying I already have node 11.2.0:

```
Simons-MBP-2:~ Simon$ brew upgrade node
Updating Homebrew...
Error: node 11.2.0 already installed
Simons-MBP-2:~ Simon$ node --version
v8.9.4
```

Could this be related to a 'path' issue. I am trying to create my vue app on a directory in my regular path where all my other projects are.

Comment: you may need [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to help you manage this situation.

Comment: hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295359/unable-to-change-version-of-node-with-brew-switch